# How to change the X-axis line from top to bottom in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph, axis

I'm new to d3.js and I couldn't understand yet why my X-axis-line is placed on top and not at the bottom (please the image bellow).

[image]

Here is the code I'm using (simplified to reduce the amount of code):

```
var data = [];
var days = ["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"];
for(var i = 0; i<7; i++){
  data.push({"letter":i,"frequency":Math.random(), "day":days[i]})
}



var svg = d3.select("#graph1"),
    margin = {top: 80, right: 20, bottom: 100, left: 100},
    width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom;


var x = d3.scaleLinear().rangeRound([0, width]),
    y = d3.scaleBand().rangeRound([0, height]);

var g = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


  x.domain([0,1]);
  y.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.day; }));

  g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x).ticks(5, "%"));

  g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis axis--y")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y))
      .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      //.attr("y", 6)
      //.attr("dy", "0.71em")
      //.attr("text-anchor", "end");



        //setup the tool

  g.append("g")         
  .attr("class", "grid")
  /*.attr("transform", "translate("+margin.left+"," + margin.top + ")")*/
  .call(d3.axisBottom(x)
        .ticks(5)
        .tickSize(height)
        .tickFormat("")
       );



var thickness = 14;
g.selectAll(".bar")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("class", "bar")
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.day) + thickness/2 ;})
    .attr("width", function(d) { return x(d.frequency);})
    .attr("height", thickness);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, I misunderstood your question. The problem is that d3-axis automatically creates a path that connects the outer 2 ticks and the axis line. In your case you have used d3-axis to create your grids. I'd assume that this path is covering your axis line at the bottom. To check that this is the case I would recommend inspecting your DOM with your browser's developer tools.

Anyways, the problem is that instead of using the d3-axis to create your grids, you should create a path for each grid line. The way you created the grid is a hack, and thats why you're seeing a line at the top. So I would get rid of:

```
g.append("g")         
    .attr("class", "grid")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x)
        .ticks(5)
        .tickSize(height)
        .tickFormat(""));
```

For the following:

```
var grid = g.append("g").attr("class","grid");
grid.selectAll("path")
    .data(x.ticks(5))
    .enter().append("path")
    .attr("d", function(d) {return "M"+x(d)+",0v"+height;});
```

**Quick Explanation**

This creates an array of tick values e.g. [0,20,40,...]:

```
    x.ticks(5)
```

The rest of the code is appending a path to the .grid group for each tick value, and then finally this code is defining the path's shape as a vertical line starting at the top and going down to the bottom of the chart.

```
.attr("d", function(d) {return "M"+x(d)+",0v"+height;})
```

Comment: I don't believe that his grid is producing the line at the top. In his code, he is only using an x-axis as a grid with tick length of `height`. That would only produce the vertical grid elements that you see in his plot. While using an axis is somewhat of a hack, it is actually a very good way to implement grids since they are very easy to scale and get working when implementing zoom and pan controls as you can easily modify them using the `d3.event.transform`. Even Mike Bostock regularly uses that approach to draw grids.

Comment: I just ran the code, and the grids part is creating the line at the top. I'm sure Bostock does it so the ] bracket shaped path at the end of the axis shows up beneath the actual axis. When you use .call(axis), it creates 4 elements, the ] bracket shaped path, a group for each tick, the line ticks, and the text for each tick.

Comment: To follow up, you'll notice that the grid lines in the attached image have the same gray as the line that @Hangon is trying to get rid of.

Comment: @JohnThompson thank you very good solution and explanation. I will use it. What for does "M" and "0v" stand in your last line for?
Thank you.

Comment: @Hangon the M in svg notation is "moveto" it moves to that point in this case the point is [x-position,0] and then v draws a vertical line from that position for the designated length, in this case the length = height. Here's the explanation of the d attribute for SVG https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/d

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the line at the top is actually from the x-axis? It looks to me like the path for your x-axis is disabled (perhaps via CSS - Highly likely if you've copy pasted from other examples as many folks disable the axis path in their charts). The only mystery is where the upper gray line is coming from... perhaps some CSS styling for the svg element? It would be useful to post a JSFiddle or plunker if you are still having trouble fixing the issue.